# Is there a way to trigger a select event after typing 3 char?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button

Im trying to trigger an event after the user types 3 character in the select input, basically ive got a service that loads all the options of the select ONLY if there are 3 chars on the textbox of the select.

How can I do that?

> My html:

```
    <fnd-extended-select label="Seleziona Insegna:" [autocomplete]="true"  [(ngModel)]="filter.ensign" (click)="ensignValues($event)">
      <fnd-option *ngFor="let p of ensignValue?.ensign" [value]="p.id">{{p.description}}</fnd-option>
    </fnd-extended-select>
```

> My component.ts:

```
  ensignValues() {

    this.accordiService.ensignValues().subscribe(
      (res: EnsignFilter) => {
        this.ensignValue = new EnsignFilter(res);
        console.log(res);

      },
      errors => {
        Utils.notifyErrors(errors, this.notificationsService);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So call that ensignValues method only if your input length is `>= 3`. For that just check the model change. But after you got results you'll need to filter them by text user typed for that you can create custom filter pipe.

```
<fnd-extended-select label="Seleziona Insegna:" [autocomplete]="true"  [(ngModel)]="filter.ensign" (change)="changed($event)">
  <fnd-option *ngFor="let p of ensignValue?.ensign" [value]="p.id">{{p.description}}</fnd-option>
</fnd-extended-select>
```

Then in component you can have methods like:

```
changed(event) {
 if(this.filter.ensign.length >= 3) {
  this.ensignValues();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done :

```
customInput : Subject<string> = new Subject();
```

in your template :

```
(ngModelChange)='inputValueChanged($event)'
```

So now listent to the event :

```
  inputValueChanged(event){
      this.customInput.next(event);
  }
```

You'll have to subscribe to your Subject in the below way :

```
this.customInput.debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(value =>{
   //call your method if value.length >=3 
});
```