# How to call a function after typing six character length in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to call a function rather than on button click , when user will type maximum 6 digits in input box from reactive form in Angular. How can I achieve this ?

**In HTML:-**

```
<form style="margin-left: 17px;" [formGroup]="otpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOtp()">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
       <input matInput placeholder="6 digit OTP" formControlName="otp" class="form-control" numbersOnly
        maxLength="6" minLength="6" required autocomplete="off">
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**TS file**

```
submitOtp(){ // call verify OTP API}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873533/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-select-event-after-typing-3-char

Comment: @optimistRohit please check my post and vote up and checked best answer so it will help to other developer to find easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `(input)` `event` on `input` tag because it will track every single character on that input field.

For Example

```js
otpForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.otpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    otp: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
}

inputHandle(event) {
  var number = event.target.value;

  if (number.length >= 6) {
    this.submitOtp();
  }
}

submitOtp() {
  console.log('call OTP API');
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="otpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOtp()">
  
        <input matInput placeholder="6 digit OTP" formControlName="otp" class="form-control" numbersOnly
         maxLength="6" minLength="6" required autocomplete="off" (input)="inputHandle($event)">
  
 </form>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sbjpod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) you can play or check

Comment: I understood. Thanks it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
this.otpForm.get('otp').valueChanges.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy),
  filter(x => x?.length === 6)
).subscribe((value) => submitOtp());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
otpForm.controls['otp'].statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
  if (status === 'VALID') {
    // call function here
  }
});
```

You will need to make sure the validators are on the reactive form and not just the html:

```js
otp = new FormControl(
  null,
  [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(6)]
)
```

Comment: His code has the max and min validations in the HTML, not in 'ts' component code (as it should in the "reactive form"). Do the status field work if these validations are just in the HTML? If it works well like that, I didn't know (I wasn't aware, because I usually work in a 'reactive way')

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero I can transform my ts file in this way and try.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this, add myFunction call at input event

```
<form style="margin-left: 17px;" [formGroup]="otpForm" (ngSubmit)="submitOtp()">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
       <input matInput placeholder="6 digit OTP" formControlName="otp" class="form-control" numbersOnly
        maxLength="6" minLength="6" required autocomplete="off" (input)="myFunction()">
 </mat-form-field>
```

In .ts file

```
myFunction = () => {
  if(this.otpForm.controls.otp.value.length === 6) {
  // your logic operation
  }
}
</form>
```